# Issue when running textcleaner from java app

Tags: centos, imagemagick, centos7

I am able to execute textcleaner from the SSH in a server, but when I tried to do the same from a Java app, textcleaner gives an error.

I already tried to change permissions with chmod and chown, and I even changed the Java app to execute using a chmod. All of this after creating the image that works as input for textcleaner.

The server is Centos 7.

The error is:

```
/opt/textcleaner -g -e stretch "<<fulldir>>/assets/invoice/89feb0bb-9ebd-46b7-a531-ba16194473e6/Aguas-Septiembre.jpg" "<<fulldir>>/assets/invoice/89feb0bb-9ebd-46b7-a531-ba16194473e6/improved_Aguas-Septiembre.jpg"
tasklist: convert: unable to open image './textcleaner_1_7206.mpc': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3143.
tasklist:
tasklist: --- FILE /var/www/invoicebox.com/public_html/assets/invoice/89feb0bb-9ebd-46b7-a531-ba16194473e6/Aguas-Septiembre.jpg NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE ---
```

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Change the line dir="." to dir="/tmp" in my script. Does that help? Sorry, I do not know how to call shell scripts from java for my textcleaner script. Did you follow all my pointers on my home page? Permission and Environment variables such as $PATH may differ from java.

Comment: CONTINUED: You probably do not have permission to save images in /opt, which is where it is trying to create and read './textcleaner_1_7206.mpc'. Changing dir to /tmp and giving tmp sufficient privileges may solve your issue. Please note that if you are going to use textcleaner in a commercial environment, then please contact me about licensing it.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 that was the issue! I changed the dir path and now it's working!
About the licences, I'm doing some research in different method to clean the images in order to do some OCR, so far I didn't get the results I was expecting.. I'm not sure if it's because of the preprocess that I'm doing to the image or because of the OCR, is there a way you can help me with that?
If I'm able to obtain the result from textcleaner and an OCR that I'm expecting, we can talk about the license

Comment: Post an example of your input image, so I can see what I can do with textcleaner and also so that I can see what your issue might be. If you want to send it privately, send to my email address listed on my home page.